# Online Offline EventListener not working

Tags: cordova

I am using online offline EventListener but its not working event.
I have place `cordova.js` before code or after code its not working at all

```
    document.addEventListener("offline", getSettinglocally, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", getSettingremotly, false);
```

`deviceReady` EventListener is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events do not fire on load of the application. They are for catching these events after the application has completely loaded and is in use. If you want to capture the network state on load of the application use something like below:

```
initialConnection: function() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL]     = true;
    states[Connection.NONE]     = false;
    global.connectionStatus = states[networkState];
    app.connectionStatus(global.connectionStatus);
    if(global.connectionStatus) {
       //do something when connected
    }
    else{
        //do something else if not
    }
}
```

And as noted in another answer for this you need the network-information plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

`offline` and `online` events are part of a this (org.apache.cordova.network-information) plugin.
For these events to work you need to have the plugin installed.

If you need some guidance on how to install a plugin into a Cordova Project please take a look at [this link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_add_plugin_features).